# How to permanentely change Apache Timeout by using include files?

Tags: apache2, timeout

If I edit Timeout in `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` then it works for awhile but eventually gets overwritten.

Now, I know it says to use the include files like pre_main_global.conf. So, do I just put `Timeout 1000` in pre_main_global.conf and rebuild and restart?

Edit:

Linux version: CentOS 7.9.2009

Apache version: 2.4.57 (cpanel)

Edit 2:

I see that httpd.conf includes additional conf files before and after Timeout is set. If I want to set Timeout in one of those additional conf files, does it matter if I put it in a conf file that is included before or after Timeout being defined?

Comment: Different distributions of Apache httpd come with different file layouts. Different versions of Linux (I'm guessing this is Linux since say the config is in /etc) handle deploying patches to config files differently. You didn't tell us what distribution / versions you are using.

Comment: I added the Linux and Apache versions to the post. I am just trying to find a simple way to permanently change the Apache Timeout. If I put it in .htaccess it causes an error. If I change it in httpd.conf it gets overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

On Centos/RHEL the configuration is in /etc/httpd/conf and /etc/httpd/conf.d

The former contains files maintained by RHEL/Centos while your stuff goes in the latter. When httpd starts, it reads /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. The last line in that file should be...

```
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

i.e. your configuration files are read after the RHEL ones. The files in conf.d are loaded in alphabetical order - it is common practice to prefix the filename with a number to ensure predictable ordering.

I therefore suggest you add a new file in /etc/httpd/conf.d, called (for example) 99-ryanslimits.conf containing your configuration.

(Where the same configuration directives are repeated in the same scope, the later one overrides the earlier).